# Saving a game with Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, save

Suppose I have a Javascript game that draws on a HTML5 canvas, it loops through updating and drawing a bunch of objects. What's the best way to go about saving the current state of the game? I guess I could loop through all the objects and write all values in text form in a format that can be read by a loading function, but that seems like quite a lot of work for both me and the game, as well as a large save file size. Is there a better way to do this? I've never done something like that before, I don't really know where to start.

Thanks.

Comment: jquery [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)? On the other hand, this will just save EVERYTHING. you may be better off writing a function that extracts relevant data only. e.g. a sprite's x/y coordinates is important. its bitmap representation isn't, since you can rebuild that easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard practice for something like this is to maintain a data model which represents your system, and a view that represents your model.  The model should be mostly data, which can be relatively complex, but it has all the information necessary for your view to render.

Assuming this model is an object tree, you can just call `var serialized = JSON.stringify(model)` to serialize your data model to a string and then `var model = JSON.parse(serialized)` to get it back.  This is a very simple, yet inflexible approach, but it is a start.

A quick way to store this information would be with `localStorage` but you will likely want to move to a back-end storage where you are putting values up to a REST service (or something like that) so that this data can be retrieved from anywhere.

I recommend looking into MVC-like frameworks like Backbone.js (for instance) which helps you to separate your models from your views, and also does a great job of persisting/hydrating your data from your data store.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. I wasn't aware you could do this, I just did a small test and it seems very practical.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do some research on the keyterms of 'serialize' and 'unserialize'.

Instead of doing a recursive loop on every object, I'd suggest that you have all your game objects implement a function for serialization.  You can use JSON to build up your entire object tree, with each object deciding what properties need to be kept, and which properties can be derived from the rest.  While this does appear to do the same thing as a recursive loops on some levels, the huge difference is that each object can define, on it's own, how to serialize/unserialize itself and it's contents..

Depending no how precisely you want to save your game state, you can reduce a LOT of data that way.  For example, maybe you can simply reset them to the beginning of the current level, or you could dump some data that's available elsewhere (level data, for example, probably shouldn't be stored in the save file, only the information on game state that lets you reproduce the level using your existing level data store).